# Create relation between two classes to allow data query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Updated, response to suggested answer provided, awaiting response before bounty award.

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I appear unable to solve this, so will put it out to bounty. For the bounty I'd like a code example/solution that solve the problem and that I can learn from.

The below code saves an object to the "mybadges" class. I'd like to have either a pointer or relation in the "FriendRequest" class connected to the mybadges class. Meaning that when I click on the pointer or relation in "FriendRequests" it returns all of the objects uploaded into the myBadges class. I then want to be able to access this data via a query.

Using Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

```
Parse.initialize("xxx", "xxx");

                var user = Parse.User.current();

                var MyBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
                var userbadges = new MyBadges();

                var Friends = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");
                var friends = new Friends();

                //var Badges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");


                //var Badges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#send").click(function () {

                        var badgeselected = $('#badgeselect .go').attr("src");
                        userbadges.set("BadgeName", badgeselected);
                        userbadges.set("uploadedBy", user);
                        //friends.set("status");
                        //friends.save();

                        userbadges.save(null, {
                            success: function (results) {
                        // The object was saved successfully.

                        friends.relation('Friends').add(userbadges);
                        //friends.save();
                        console.log(user);

                        //location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (contact, error) {
                        // The save failed.
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
                        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    }
                });
                    });
                });


                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $('.go').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
                $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');


                $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal


                });
                return false;
               });
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a one-to-many relationship there are a couple of options:

- Use "back reference" links, i.e. add a `friendRequest` pointer to your `myBadges` class (only supports *one-to-many*)
- Add a column of type Array (good for small lists, supports *many-to-many*)
- Add a column of type Relation (use queries to navigate, supports *many-to-many*)
- Create a custom class to hold the relationships (if you have other data about each join, supports *many-to-many*)
  The simplest option is using the Array column, in JavaScript you just use a normal array that contains `myBadges` instances and assign it to a property of your parent class.

**Note**: In my examples below, I'm going to change the case of call classes to UpperCamel singular (myBadges -> MyBadge) and all properties/column names to lowerCamel (BadgeName -> badgeName) for consistency, and I suggest you do the same.

**Examples:**

Common code assumed in the below:

```
var FriendRequest = Parse.Object.extend("FriendRequest");
var MyBadge = Parse.Object.extend("MyBadge");
var friendRequest = /* some FriendRequest you've loaded */
```

---

**Option 1 - back-reference**

Adding new badge to a friend request:

```
// MyBadge.friendRequest: Pointer (to FriendRequest)
var myBadge = new MyBadge();
myBadge.set({
    badgeName: someStringVariable,
    uploadedBy: someUserObject,
    friendRequest: friendRequest
});
myBadge.save();
```

Getting badges for a friend request:

```
var badgesQuery = new Parse.Query(MyBadge);
badgesQuery.equalTo('friendRequest', friendRequest);
badgesQuery.find({
    success: function(badges) {
        // use badges as needed...
    }
});
```

Showing MyBadge rows for FriendRequest parent in Data Browser:

Get the `objectId` of a FriendRequest row, then on the view for `MyBadge` add a filter on the `friendRequest` column and paste the ID.

---

**Option 2 - Array**

Adding new badge to a friend request:

```
// FriendRequest.badges: Array (of MyBadge)

// 2-step process, first create and save the MyBadge instance
var myBadge = new MyBadge();
myBadge.set({
    badgeName: someStringVariable,
    uploadedBy: someUserObject
});
myBadge.save()
// step 2 (using chaining here) attach the saved badge to the friend request
.then(function() {
    friendRequest.badges.addUnique(myBadge);
    // return promise to allow further chaining
    return friendRequest.save();
});
```

Getting badges for a friend request:

```
// just include them when querying for FriendRequest objects
friendRequestQuery.include('badges');
```

Showing MyBadge rows for FriendRequest parent in Data Browser:

No support for this, you'll need to create your own solution.

---

**Option 3 - Relation**

Adding new badge:

```
// FriendRequest.badges: Relation (of MyBadge)

// 2-step process, first create and save the MyBadge instance
var myBadge = new MyBadge();
myBadge.set({
    badgeName: someStringVariable,
    uploadedBy: someUserObject
});
myBadge.save()
// step 2 (using chaining here) attach the saved badge to the friend request
.then(function() {
    var badgesRelation = friendRequest.relation('badges');
    badgesRelation.add(myBadge);
    // return promise to allow further chaining
    return friendRequest.save();
});
```

Getting badges for a friend request:

```
// query the relation
var badgesRelation = friendRequest.relation('badges');
var badgesQuery = badgesRelation.query();
// apply any filters as you would for any normal Parse.Query()
// ...
// use find() or any other query method
badgesQuery.find({
    success: function(badges) {
        // use array of badges...
    }
})
```

Showing MyBadge rows for FriendRequest parent in Data Browser:

Double-click on a value in the `badges` column.

---

**Option 4 - custom join class**

This isn't really suitable for your use-case, so I'm not going to provide a sample here.

Comment: Thank you again, are you saying its not suitable to use a pointer for the above? the parse docs seem to suggest it is? https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers I also understood using an array could be limiting if the child objects numbered over 100+ ?

Comment: A pointer is for a pointer to a single object. An array can contain multiple pointers. If you're going to have more than 100 children, look at using a Relation, there's plenty of docs that explain how to use a Relation that you should read first, then post another question if you're still stuck.

Comment: I've added a bounty to solve this as I'm banging my head against a wall. See the updated question if your interested.

Comment: @Dano007 I added some sample code, I strongly recommend using a back-reference in the scenario you've given.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answers, I think these will help the SO community greatly. Regarding my issues, I've followed option 1. I need some validation of what I've done, there fore see the following jfiddles that hold the code for saving and pulling the badges. Could you validate these are correct. jsfiddle.net/Dano007/Lst76/3 and jsfiddle.net/Dano007/HSne9/1/I've added images of the DO structure to make sure this is correct? Perhaps we could discuss this on "chat" if your free today? might solve it quicker.. Many thanks –

Comment: In your first jsfiddle, you're creating a new `FriendRequest` without saving it. You have to save it first or reference an existing one. In the 2nd jsfiddle, you either need to load a `FriendRequest` to attach to the `MyBadge` or use one you've already loaded. If you want to chat I'm OK with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55649/discussion-between-dano007-and-timothy-walters).

Comment: I've got this working, but there are still some minor issues that mean it doesn't appear to work 100% correctly. I've created the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/c9U5Y/ if we can sort these I'm happy to get the bounty awarded. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Timothy Walters Same url in discussion will now take you to the working code